# About semantic web, RDF and OWL

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web

what is the relationship between RDF and OWL?

It seems like RDF is used to describe web resources, does OWL can do the same thing? Or OWL only can describe the web ontologies? I am so confused about the relationship between them and what's the role of each in semantic web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some good answers already. One point I would highlight is that OWL gives you a vocabulary for making *logical* assertions about the resources you want to describe. For example, in RDF you can say *"this resource, `:r` is a car, because it is a member of the class of all cars which I've named `:Car`"*. You can also say *"this resource `:r` is a bacterium, because it is a member of the class `:Bacteria`"*. What you can't do in RDF is say *"hang on, that's not consistent: no one thing can be both a car and a bacterium"* because RDF has no way of expressing that. Using OWL, you could also say *"the classes `:Car` and `:Bacteria` are disjoint: by definition they have no members in common"*. Being disjoint is example of one of the logical assertions you can state in OWL that you can't state in RDF.

Whether that matters to you is entirely dependent on your application. The logical assertions defined by OWL come with a formal, mathematical semantics which allows them to be processed by a reasoning engine. This could, for example, be used to notice that a user has accidentally asserted `:r` to be an impossible car/bug, and notify them. Or it could be used to conclude new information that's implicit in your set of descriptions, but isn't explicitly stated. For some applications, this kind of formal reasoning is essential, for others it's irrelevant.

Comment: Does it mean that we can write a RDF file to describe some resources, and we can describe the relationship between those resources by using OWL in an another file? So I should have the RDF file before using OWL?

Comment: Yes and no :) Yes you can modularise the information into as many files as you want. The relationships *between resources* would normally be described in RDF, it's the *nature of the relationship* that OWL can help you articulate. Since StackOverflow likes to have one question per page, if you'd like more advice I suggest you create a new question topic with an actual example that you are trying to model. Then we can make some specific suggestions under that topic.

Answer (score 4):

OWL (Web Ontology Language) is used for formally describing ontologies. It is not used to describe the actual resources (but you can create instances in your ontology, too. Yes, in a sense it is confusing at the beginning, I'm sorry) but rather provide meta-data about them (classes, sub-classes, properties, sub-properties, domains and ranges of properties, etc.). As a very crude approximation you can think of OWL and RDFS (RDF Schema) being in the same category and you can think of RDF as the underlying (somewhat abstract) language that is used to express everything in the world of semantic web (including actual resources as well as descriptions in OWL and RDFS).

For a detailed introduction I suggest the following online introductions:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/

For a (possibly) gentle introduction as a very readable book I suggest:

- http://workingontologist.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you're just generating, or consuming Semantic Web data (RDF) you don't need to worry bout OWL. It's a machine readable schema language for RDF data, but you can get by understanding the human readable text, or examples used for the type of data you're interested in.

The relationship is a bit complex as OWL files are written in RDF, and describe RDF data.

I've been working with SemWeb technologies in industry for 6 years, and never once in that time had to read or write an OWL file. Prior to that I was working in a research lab, and we sometimes used OWL there.

Comment: do you mean u don't have to write OWL in a text editor, but still use a gui tool like Protege? what if u have to upgrade the Knowledge that can't be found somehow.

Answer (score 1):

OWL is a more advanced language than RDF. It has some abilities that RDF can't express, such as :

• express relationships among classes defined in different documents across the Web;

• construct new classes by unions, intersections, and complements of other existing classes;

• add constraints on the number and type for properties of classes;

• determine if all members of a class will have a particular property, or if only some of them might;

• express if a property is symmetric, asymmetric, transitive, etc.